# Why does $y_{n+1} - y_n \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

> Let $f(x) = x\ln x$. Let the sequence $\{y_n\}$ such that $f(y_n) = y_n\cdot \ln y_n = n\pi$.
>
> Why does $y_{n+1} - y_n \to 0$?

Obviously $y_n$ diverges, but we need to prove that the terms in the sequence are getting closer and closer.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is $\ln x + 1$ but I don't how it's helping.

Comment: What is the $n\pi$ on the first sentence?

Comment: it's the corresponding $n$ for $y_n$.

Comment: $y_n\sim n/\log n$.

Comment: Thank you all. idk which answer to mark since all of them helped me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
f(y_{n+1})-f(y_n)=(n+1)\pi-n\,\pi=\pi.
$$
On the other hand, by the mean value theorem
$$
f(y_{n+1})-f(y_n)=(y_{n+1}-y_n)f'(z_n)\ge(y_{n+1}-y_n)(\ln(y_n)+1).
$$
Thus
$$
y_{n+1}-y_n\le\frac{\pi}{\ln(y_n)+1}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $y_n = f^{-1}(n\pi)$.

Since $f(x)$ is increasing towards $+\infty$ (for $x>1$) and its derivative also increases towards $+\infty$, the derivative of its *inverse* must *decrease* towards $0$.

Therefore the Mean Value Theorem will allow you to bound the difference between $f^{-1}((n+1)\pi)$ and $f^{-1}(n\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

We look at $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(y_{n+1})-f(y_n)}{y_{n+1}-y_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{y_{n+1}-y_n}$$
Since this is an approximation to the derivative of $f$ (more specific, this is the slope of the line from $(y_n,f(y_n))$ to $(y_{n+1},f(y_{n+1}))$), and we know that the derivative of $f$ is equal to $f'(x)=\log(x)+1$, we know that the above limit goes to infinity. To support this more, note that $f$ is convex (on $\mathbb{R}^+$), so we know that the slope of the line must be *more* than the derivative of $f$ in the point $y_n$. Now we know

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{y_{n+1}-y_n}=+\infty$$
so we also know
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{y_{n+1}-y_n}=0$$

I know this is an intuitional proof, but I'm sure you can make this a "real" mathematically correct proof.

Hope this helped!